# widget menu does not appear in wordpress admin menu

Tags: wordpress, widget, sidebar

im trying to create my own widget area in my theme. This is the code i used in function.php

function front_widget_area(){

```
 register_sidebars ( 3, $args)
 $args = array(
'name'          => __('row1 %d'),
'id'            => 'row1',
'description'   => '',
'class'         => '',
'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
'after_widget'  => '</li>',
'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
'after_title'   => '</h2>' );
  }
```

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'front_widget_area' );

i've not yet implemeted the code part related to the page where i want to place the widget. The question is. When i put this code in function.php the widget menu shoud be visible in the admin panel isn't it?..but is not, could someone try to help me figuring out why? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use to create widgets

```
register_sidebar(array(
        'id' => '',
        'name' => '',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '',
        'after_title' => '',
));
```

I usually don't wrap my widget code around a function, I just placed this as is in the function file.

Hope this helps

Comment: so without add_action()?

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me.

```
$sidebar_args = array(
    'name'          => __('row1 %d'),
    'id'            => 'row1',          
    'description'   => '',
    'class'         => '',
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</li>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>' 
);
register_sidebars ( 3, $sidebar_args);
```

It seems that `register_sidebars` doesn't need the `add_action` line.
`add_action` is required when you want to register only one sidebar.

[WP Codex - register_sidebars](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebars)